# Ubuntu server 18.04 - Installing desktop and nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, desktop-environments

I'm hoping to get some help getting ubuntu desktop and current nvidia drivers installed over a fresh server installation of 18.04 (as to support my software raid configuration).  Historically, I had this working when I built my system using 14.04.  Last semester I needed to install Tensorflow, and the nvidia driver that came along with it resulted in no output from the GPU.  I didn't have time to fix it, so I just used the system as headless.  Rather than wade through the OS upgrade swamp and fix the driver issue, I decided it was time to upgrade to 18.04.

I seem to be able to do one or the other in 18.04 - get ubuntu desktop or nvidia drivers working - but not both.  I've re-installed ubuntu so we can start from a blank page.

Thanks for help / guidance on what should be installed first and troubleshooting advice along the way.

Where things stand:
-Server flavor of 18.04 installed
-Boots to black screen on restart
-Can boot to tty by adding nomodeset to the grub boot line
-If I do this, the nouveau drivers are loaded (lsmod | grep nvidia returns nothing, lsmod | grep nouveau shows it is loaded)

Where I'd like to be:
-Nvidia 440 drivers installed (newest compatible with my graphics card) so I can run cuda / tensorflow
-Functional desktop

System stats:
-Xeon E5-2630 v3 (8 core / 16 thread)
-Quadro M4000
-HP LA2206 monitor (1920x1080 resolution)
-64 gb RAM
-Asrock EPC612D8 motherboard
-6X 1 tb western digital black hard drives (software raid 6)